# Unable to record video and take frames from onPreviewFrame callback at the same time

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I am recording video in my Android application using `MediaRecorder` and I also want frame data through the `onPreviewFrame` callback.

**The issue is:** If preview is restarted in `surfaceChanged` callback then video recording stops working. If it is not restarted, by commenting everything inside `surfaceChanged`, then video recording keeps working but the `onPreviewFrame` callback stops working.

How can I make both of them work?

CameraActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = mPreview.getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
        }

        startLockTask();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            prepareMediaRecorder();
            startVideoRecording();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {

    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int what, int extra) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Media recorder error");
            }
        });

        mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                    stopVideoRecording();
                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                    prepareMediaRecorder();
                    startVideoRecording();
                }
            }
        });

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        //mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
//        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(3);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(6000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(800, 480);
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000);

        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
//        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void startVideoRecording() {
        mMediaRecorder.start();
        isRecording = true;
    }

    private void stopVideoRecording() {
        // stop recording and release camera
        mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
        isRecording = false;
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

activity_camera.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For the old Camera API, you would need to direct the preview to a SurfaceTexture, and then render that twice, once for the display and once for recording (see e.g. https://github.com/google/grafika). With Camera2 I believe you can configure multiple output Surfaces. What's your minimum API requirement?

Comment: @fadden 21. So I can use Camera2. But I could not understand why `SurfaceTexture` would work and `SurfaceView` won't? How is this related to the `onPreviewFrame` callback?

Comment: The old Camera API could only forward frames to one destination. Taking a picture stopped the preview. Sending frames to a SurfaceTexture doesn't change that, but once you have the frame in a GLES texture you can render it as many times as you like.

Comment: is there any proper solution available? can you please guide me?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost similar to link provided below but here they used TextureView instead of Surface View and custom CameraView class.

This worked for me, hope helps you too

REF : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder

Comment: what are you talking about? that sample doesn't even contain `onPreviewFrame` method